# Insert Data into Table Where Table Name is Dynamic?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I had a Requirement that,Insert into data into table where as Table Name is Dynamic Here Is the actual Query:-

```
INSERT INTO GENERATEBARCODE (BARCODEID, AMUID, GROSS_WT, TARE_WT, PRODUCTCODE, BATCHNO, PREVBARCODEID, LOT, UNAME, STAGE, STATUS)
    SELECT DISTINCT BARCODEID, 'DISPENSEHOLD', IT.GROSS_QUANTITY, IT.TARE_QUANTITY, BM.PRODUCT_CODE, IT.BATCH_NO, 'NA', LOT, 'NA', 'START', 'INPROCESS'
    FROM inserted IT INNER JOIN
         DISPENSE_HOLD BM
         ON IT.BATCH_NO = BM.BATCH_NO;
```

Here Table Name Vary Dynamically 
I had a Variable Which Gives `01,02,03 etc`
Data should be inserted dynamically into table based on variable value like `Generatebarcode+'01'` .How Could I do that?

Comment: You have to build dynamic query for this.

Comment: `insert into Table(col1, col2) exec ('select * from Generatebarcode' + @variable)`

Comment: You have something wrong with your data model.  Having multiple tables with the same columns only distinguished by a number is a sign of a problem with the design.

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to partition tables manually. Let the *server* do it. SQL Server provided partitioning in Enterprise editions up to 2016. Since 2016 SP1 even SQL Server Express has partitioning

Comment: @BhatiaAshish I want to insert into Table(Here table name should be dynamic)

Comment: @saibharath that's what you think you want. What you describe though is *partitioning* and you probably *don't* need any dynamic queries - there are no "dynamic tables" in SQL.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Yeah I know but That's requirement Can't help so giving a try

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I'm using 2008 version

Comment: @saibharath even in Standard Edition you can create an updatable [partitioned view](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-view-transact-sql#partitioned-views) that combines all tables with UNION. If you specify the proper constraints on the table, the optimizer will know which table to insert to.

Comment: @saibharath what edition? Partitioning was already available in 2008 Enterprise. Try a partitioned view otherwise. Read-only partitioned views were already available in 2000

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Iam using 2008 R 2 Edition Iam unaware of this concept please throw some light on this

Comment: @saibharath 2008 R2 is the *version* not the edition. Editions are Express, Workgroup, Standard, Enterprise. And I already provided links in the comments. The link shows examples, explains the requirements to create a partitioned view and even has links to partitioned tables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way you can achieve this is using dynamic query like following.

```
DECLARE @VER VARCHAR(10)
SET @VER='01'
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @SQL = N'INSERT INTO GENERATEBARCODE' + @VER + ' (BARCODEID, AMUID, GROSS_WT, TARE_WT, PRODUCTCODE, BATCHNO, PREVBARCODEID, LOT, UNAME, STAGE, STATUS)
    SELECT DISTINCT BARCODEID, ''DISPENSEHOLD'', IT.GROSS_QUANTITY, IT.TARE_QUANTITY, BM.PRODUCT_CODE, IT.BATCH_NO, ''NA'', LOT, ''NA'', ''START'', ''INPROCESS''
    FROM inserted IT INNER JOIN
         DISPENSE_HOLD BM
         ON IT.BATCH_NO = BM.BATCH_NO;'

EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL
```

Comment: There are ways to work with partitions that are far faster and safer, eg partitioned views or partitioned tables

Comment: It showing error incorrect syntax Near Inserted @PSK

Comment: It should be giving "Invalid object name 'inserted'.", you yourself using the table name "inserted" in your query. You need to give the correct table name

Comment: Actually its a trigger.Before this I never got this error @PSK